# docker-compose unable to find valid certification path javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException

Tags: ssl, docker-compose, pkix

I use docker-compsoe and got an error like: "javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target"

according to [this link][1], i run following command

sudo keytool -import -noprompt -trustcacerts -alias myalias -file mycert -keystore /usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk-amd64/lib/security/cacerts -storepass changeit

but still I got the same error:
"javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target"

Is there anything to be added to the docker-compose file?

or how to disable ssl certificate to avoid this error?
[1]: ["PKIX path building failed" and "unable to find valid certification path to requested target"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21076179/pkix-path-building-failed-and-unable-to-find-valid-certification-path-to-requ)